# Display data from Firebase Realtime Database in Ionic App

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to display all the children of "Requests" in my firebase realtime database inside a list like .
This is how my realtime database looks like:

[image]

So far i have been able to get the data from firebase in form of JSON .

requests.page.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RequestsService } from '../requests.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { element } from 'protractor';

u/Component({
 selector: 'app-requests',
 templateUrl: './requests.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./requests.page.scss'],
})
export class RequestsPage implements OnInit {
 requests:Promise<any[]>;
 requestsList : any[] = [];

constructor(
 private requestsService: RequestsService,
 private firebaseDB: AngularFireDatabase,
  ) { }

 ngOnInit() {

    {  var ref = this.firebaseDB.database.ref('/Requests/').once('value').then(function (data){

 var jsonRequest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( data.val()));
 console.log("JSONREQUEST :????>>>>>>>" + JSON.stringify(jsonRequest) );
 requests = this.jsonRequest;
 
    })
  }

}
```

requests.page.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>requests</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let r of requests | async">
      <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">
        {{r.name}}<br>
        <p>{{r.bloodGroup}}</p>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item >
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I get this out put in the console

```js
JSONREQUEST :????>>>>>>>{"-MaTAKR8qxebin2dcVhp":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"AB+","location":"Kolkata","message":"Need Blood Urjently","name":"Hemant Baid","phoneNumber":"7865436789","reason":"Thalassemia","timestamp":1621856442436,"type":"Whole Blood","uid":"Bstt2BRdvAPodfSlUT9367a8DB52"},"-MaTvIvdjH1XpN7mHfoi":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"AB+","location":"Kolkata","message":"f","name":"Hemant Baid","phoneNumber":"7865436789","reason":"Thalassemia","timestamp":1621869019139,"type":"Whole Blood","uid":"Bstt2BRdvAPodfSlUT9367a8DB52"},"-MaU01T98spFheBGXdEh":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"AB+","location":"Kolkata","message":"a","name":"Hemant Baid","phoneNumber":"7865436789","reason":"Thalassemia","timestamp":1621870520547,"type":"Whole Blood","uid":"Bstt2BRdvAPodfSlUT9367a8DB52"},"-MaU3-PF5JDxBgr4dMkK":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"A+","location":"Mumbai","message":"a","name":"Hemant Baid","phoneNumber":"7865436789","reason":"Transplant","timestamp":1621871298520,"type":"Whole Blood","uid":"Bstt2BRdvAPodfSlUT9367a8DB52"},"-MaUDTcYPNvCoxoNTze-":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"AB+","location":"Siliguri,West Bengal","message":"qwert","name":"Hemant Baid","phoneNumber":"7865436789","reason":"Transplant","timestamp":1621874043756,"type":"Double Red Cell","uid":"Bstt2BRdvAPodfSlUT9367a8DB52"},"-MaUSkPxPlM-ihK00cVa":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"B-","location":"Delhi","message":"hsodn","name":"Nilabja Das ","phoneNumber":"9876545678","reason":"Other","timestamp":1621878049000,"type":"I don't know","uid":"L0A6M57zXJaXzoSp1RCZMD5WCXm2"},"-MaUTBArFaLAy_TV0SeO":{"ID":"Request","bloodGroup":"AB-","location":"Kandi,West Bengal","message":"location test","name":"Nilabja Das ","phoneNumber":"9876545678","reason":"Thalassemia","timestamp":1621878162707,"type":"Cord Blood","uid":"L0A6M57zXJaXzoSp1RCZMD5WCXm2"}}
```

After compiling the list is empty and nothing is displayed on the screen. Can someone please explain me what am i doing wrong.

EDITED :
After removing everything inside then and having only console.log(data) I get this output:

[image]

RE-EDITED:

console.log(data.val());

[image]

Comment: Using keyword function after then makes the typescript not working, replace function (data) with (data) =>

Comment: After that u will see the typescript errors,then it comest to be this.requests = jsonRequest and that should solve the problem but first be sure to change the word function with what i said in above comment..

Comment: I did both the things. The data is still not displayed in the <ion-list> and I get the following error in the console - ` InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Comment: First whole opperarion u are doing is wrong,u are using json parse and then json strinfigy which is wierd thing to do, just do console.log(data) and kindly attach the response that is viewed in web console to ur question so i can tive u the solution..

Comment: When i console.log(data) it just gives me `[object Object]` in the console with the same error `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`.

Comment: Yes thats because u still have json.stringify, remove everything inside then, and just put console.log(data) without anything else...

Comment: Please check i have edited the question with the screenshot of what i get in the console after removing everything inside then and just having (console.log(data))

Comment: Ok if u console.log(data.val()) what will the response be?

Comment: Please check i have again re edited the question with a screenshot of console.log(data.val()). It is now giving me the data from my firebase realtime database.

Comment: Ok as u can see, no need to json parse since json parse is used in case the response was already stringified from server side. So what u need is just to use the data as it is. Now if we come to the response data, you can see a random generated key and inside it ur objects... so what u need is using map function in order to remove the random keys and just get the objects u need... give me some minutes and i'll give you the correct way to write the function.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Thanks a lot. This is my first week with javascript. I come from Java background and things have gotten very interesting for me.

Comment: https://jsmobiledev.com/article/crud-ionic-firestore, see the firebaseService getSongList(), it should let u know the way to get values as u need

Comment: I see its using Cloud Firestore but I am using Realtime Database. How can I do it in Realtime Database?

Comment: Ah ok, give some time till i  reach my pc, i'll give u the answer ASAP, be sure i'll reply after few hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233388/discussion-between-arnab-and-mostafa-harb).

Comment: I've added the answer how it should go, and tomorrow if i got time, i'll send u the map way to solve that problem but still working from phone and want to give u ur answer till i reach my computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You declare and access `requests` as `Promise<any[]>` but I don't see where it's assigned a value that is a promise.
2. You `console.log` the variable `jsonRequest`, but then set `requests` to `this.jsonRequest;`.

It's possible that #1 doesn't actually matter technically, I'm not familiar enough with Angular to say for sure, but it still seems wrong...

Comment: I am not only new to Angular but also Javascript. I was just trying out things to see if it works. Can you please tell me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RequestsService } from '../requests.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { element } from 'protractor';

u/Component({
 selector: 'app-requests',
 templateUrl: './requests.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./requests.page.scss'],
})
export class RequestsPage implements OnInit {
 requests:Promise<any[]>;
 requestsList : any[] = [];

constructor(
 private requestsService: RequestsService,
 private firebaseDB: AngularFireDatabase,
  ) { }

 ngOnInit() {

    {  var ref = this.firebaseDB.database.ref('/Requests/').once('value').then((data) => {
    const response_data = data.val();
    const requests = [];
    for (const key in response_data) {
         if (response_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             requests.push(response_data[key]);
        }
    }

     this.requests = requests;
    })
  }

}
```

And for previewing in html, just put *ngFor="let request of requests" and keep the same things u made as field names and it will get its values..